# How to change x axis format from d3.js line charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts, linechart

I am trying to modify the chart http://bl.ocks.org/gniemetz/4618602 (D3.js).

I want remove the date format of the X axis and get numerical values of  'Gesamt' column (data.txt), example:

214-------220--------234---------255 (x axis)

I've tried to remove all occurrences of "formatDate" code, but does not work. What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

Data import is happening here:

```
d3.csv("data.txt", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Uhrzeit = parseDate(d.Uhrzeit);
    d.Durchschn = +d.Durchschn;
    d.Anz = +d.Anz;
  });
```

`d` is each row or observation. If you want to use `Gesamt` instead of `Uhrzeit`, this is where you need to make the adjustments.

Comment: Thanks, but I change this to "d.Uhrzeit = d.Gesamt;" or "d.Gesamt = d.Gesamt;" or "d.Uhrzeit = +d.Gesamt;" and dont work...